# Linear regression and multicollinearity

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, linear

There is a multiple linear regression model being created.

Y=ax1+bx2+cx3

Following HYPOTHESES are formed

Variable x does not impact y

for all variables x1, x2 , x3 and so on.

We removed a variable , say , x2 because of high VIF value from regression model but that means it is highly correlated with x1 or x3.

What would happen to your HYPOTHESES for x2? Is it REJECTED?

Please clarify if feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Your hypotheses can only relate to one model. In your model with three predictors, you have three hypotheses. If you decide to remove one of the variables, the model changes, and you cannot compare hypotheses. In particular, there is no sensible hypothesis for $x_2$ anymore, but also, the hypotheses for $x_1$ and $x_3$ are no longer comparable to the "previous" ones.

This system of hypothesis testing does not answer the question "does $x_2$ influence $y$" in general. It only answers it with respect to a model that has to be specified.

More precisely, "does $x$ influence $y$" is more a question of causality, which you also cannot answer within this framework.

Comment: More precisely, "does x influence y" is more a question of causality, which you also cannot answer within this framework. Can u explain a bit more because even if x2 is removed, linear regression model with x1 and x3 confirms causality or causation?

Comment: It doesn't confirm causality or causation in general. In specific circumstances, typically in clinical settings, with a control group and such, researchers do claim a causal effect: "this medicine causes faster recovery". But with typical data, that was not obtained through some experimental design, a linear regression is not enough to show causal relations, if you don't carefully consider and assume a whole load of other assumptions on your observations. There is interesting progress being made in this area though, and I would recommend "The Book of Why" http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/WHY/.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, "does x influence y" is more a question of causality, which you also cannot answer within this framework.
Can u explain a bit more because even if x2 is removed , linear regression model with x1 and x3 confirms causality or causation?